# Android-Image Size change When get Focused

Tags: android

I am new to android.I am trying to make the image to get to zoom out to a particular level when is get Focused and when the Focus is gone then the image should go to original size automatically.I don't want to zoom in and out a image. I just want that image to change size when it is get focused and once focus is gone it should get it to original size same as in iPhone.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use View.setOnFocusChangeListener 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener(android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener)